# How to style a mutiple select box so it always displays every option?

Tags: html, css

I have a multiple select box that is dynamically populated.  I want all of the options to be displayed, rather than a limited size.  Is there an attribute that allows this or other method to cause all options to display?

Comment: Maybe you could use a column of check boxes instead.  It's also more friendly to the user than having to ctrl-click to do multiple selects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTML attribute `size` to indicate the number of options you'll want to display. I'd figure out the number of options through your script and add that number to the `size` attribute.

`<select name="select" multiple size="10">`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute that will cause it to change size dynamically, but you can always use Javascript to dynamically change the height of the select box. Note of caution though: this might not work on older versions of IE, or IE set to a lower compatibility mode.